# WinHTTP Send() with parameters

Tags: json, rest, http-post, autoit, winhttp

I have a list of inputs to be sent as part of a HTTP POST request. I am searching for an AutoIt equivalent to encapsulate this data. Below code is failing with `400 - Bad Request` for incomplete input (unable to send *ip_list* and other *array type* parameters).

1. How to encapsulate the data for `$oHttp.Send()`?
2. How to encapsulate data types like:

   - null - *aligned_device_template* parameter
   - white-spaced values - *description*
   - empty array - *hostname* or *device_groups*

Input parameters in JSON:

```
{
      "name": "SnmpSIM",
      "description": "EM7 device created by BDD test case",
      "credentials":"{{feature.credential.body.result_set[*].URI}}", 
      "organization": "/api/organization/0",
      "aligned_device_template": null,
      "aligned_collector": "{{feature.appliance_id[0].id[0]}}{{feature.appliance_id[0].id[1]}}",
      "discover_non_snmp": "1",
      "scan_ports": [
        "21",
        "22",
        "23",
        "25",
        "80"
      ],
      "ip_lists": [
        {
        "start_ip": "{{feature.json.ip}}",
        "end_ip": "{{feature.json.ip}}"
        }
      ],
      "dhcp_enabled": "0",
      "duplicate_protection": "1",
      "model_device": "1",
      "log_all": "1",
      "scan_all_ips": null,
      "port_scan_timeout": null,
      "initial_scan_level": null,
      "scan_throttle": null,
      "interface_inventory_timeout": "600000",
      "max_interface_inventory_count": "10000",
      "bypass_interface_inventory": "0",
      "hostnames": [],
      "device_groups": []
    }
```

My code:

```
; The data to be sent
$sPD = 'name=SnmpSIM&description=EM7 device created by BDD test case&credentials=37&organization=/api/organization/0&aligned_device_template=null&aligned_collector=1&discover_non_snmp=1&dhcp_enabled=0&duplicate_protection=1&model_device=1&log_all=1&scan_all_ips= null&port_scan_timeout= null&initial_scan_level= null&scan_throttle= null&interface_inventory_timeout=600000&max_interface_inventory_count=10000&bypass_interface_inventory=0&hostnames=&device_groups=&scan_ports=21'

; Creating the object
$oHTTP = ObjCreate("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
$oHTTP.Open("POST", "http://10.2.4.18/api/discovery_session", False)
$oHTTP.SetCredentials("username","password",0)

$oHTTP.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/em7-resource-uri")

; Performing the Request
$oHTTP.Send($sPD)

; Download the body response if any, and get the server status response code.
$oReceived = $oHTTP.ResponseText
$oStatusCode = $oHTTP.Status

If $oStatusCode <> 200 then
 MsgBox(4096, "Response code", $oStatusCode)
EndIf

; Saves the body response regardless of the Response code
 $file = FileOpen("Received.html", 2) ; The value of 2 overwrites the file if it already exists
 FileWrite($file, $oReceived)
 FileClose($file)
```

Sample VBA code for reference:

```
 Dim Items As New Collection
 Dim Item As Dictionary
 Dim Id As Long

 For Id = 1 To 2
     Set Item = New Dictionary
     Item("iditem") = Id
     Item("amount") = 1
     Items.Add Item
 Next Id
 Request.AddBodyParameter "id", 5633
 Request.AddBodyParameter "items", Items

$oDictionary = ObjCreate("Scripting.Dictionary")
$oDictionary.ADD("start_ip", "10.20.7.31")
$oDictionary.ADD("end_ip", "10.20.7.33")
```

Comment: Search for json UDF's for autoit. They exist and I have used one before. They should allow you to add data to a json object and then send it as a string in the post body.